# numpy Invalid datetime unit generic in metadata error

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on updating someone else's code from numpy 1.6.1 to numpy 1.8.

The code that is giving an error(and my added print, which won't even work):

```
        for name in arr.dtype.names:
            print name
            print arr.dtype.names
            print arr
            print arr[name]
            set_to_nan(arr[name])
```

The printout and then the error:

```
time
('time', 'nsec', 'SeqNum', 'message_offset', 'event_type', 'match_event_locator', 'trdpx', 'trdqty', 'trdaggr', 'trdtyp', 'trdid', 'bid', 'ask')
```

[ `(None, 32128, -1146166105165789278, 1, 0, 0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, '', [(0.0, 0, 0), (0.0, 0, 0), (0.0, 0, 0), (0.0, 0, 0), (0.0, 0, 0), (0.0, 0, 0), (0.0, 0, 0), (0.0, 0, 0), (0.0, 0, 0), (0.0, 0, 0)], [(0.0, 0, 0), (0.0, 0, 0), (0.0, 0, 0), (0.0, 0, 0), (0.0, -938012672, 5), (0.0, 536870912, 25211), (0.0, 0, 12288), (1.4916681462400413e-154, 527891, 0), (0.0, 48070656, 10), (0.0, 1879048192, 1)])]`

Error from trying to print arr[name]

```
  File "/home/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dat/array_utils.py", line 500, in set_to_nan
    print arr[name]
  File "/home/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1615, in array_str
    return array2string(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small, ' ', "", str)
  File "/home/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 454, in array2string
    separator, prefix, formatter=formatter)
  File "/home/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 328, in _array2string
    _summaryEdgeItems, summary_insert)[:-1]
  File "/home/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 500, in _formatArray
    word = format_function(a[-1])
  File "/home/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 741, in __call__
    casting=self.casting)
TypeError: Invalid datetime unit "generic" in metadata
```

If I let the code run without the print, I get this:

```
  File "/home/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dat/array_utils.py", line 487, in set_to_nan
    arr[:] = _dtype_nan_value(arr.dtype)
ValueError: Cannot convert from specific units to generic units in NumPy datetimes or timedeltas
```

Comment: Pdb is your friend. E.g., type ``%debug`` in IPython after the error and inspect the types of your variables.